# AuthenticationBuilder does not contain a definition for Google

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, .net-6.0

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{facebookOptions.AppId = "xxxxx";
 facebookOptions.AppSecret = "xxxxx";
});

services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{   googleOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});`
```

For FaceBook works fine. What is the problem for Google? I cant find any kind of package in the NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google) nuget package.